# Oracle Trigger Only Fires After I do a explicit Commit

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am new to triggers and just learning them. When I delete a row from the respective table I do not get a DBMS Output, but I know the row has been deleted. The only time I get a DBMS output for the trigger is when do a COMMIT or a RollBACK. Is this correct? Form what I have read the Trigger should automatically run when I delete a row but that doesn't seem to be the case for me. Additionally I ensured the trigger was enabled and set serveroutput was on.

```
create or replace Trigger tadr_Employee
    After Delete ON employee
    For Each Row
    Begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Tigger Fired After deleting anything from Lab10_Employees tadr');
    End;

Delete FROM Employee
Where EmployeeID = 11111;
```

Comment: The trigger fires immediately. The problem is that `DBMS_OUTPUT` messages are buffered in the memory and appear only if `commit` is executed. BTW. `DBMS_OUTPUT`  is intended for debugging purposes only, do not use it in a production code, because you will get an `buffer overflow` error.

Comment: Thanks, Is there oracle documentation for this? This is a HW question and I'd like to site the source. Also the HW question seems to indicate that I should be getting DBMS Output after I run the DELETE, which prompted my question on here.

Comment: Yes there are tons of documentation, [Pl/SQL Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm), /  [Create trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7004.htm#SQLRF01405), /  [DBMS_Output](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS036)